# How to start a process only after one process has completed?

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 functions I created which does specific works.
I call these functions on timers. But before function 1 completes, function 2 starts processing. How can I wait till 1 completes before starting 2.

Here is my code:

```cs
private void btnrun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        _bat.ShowDialog();
                StrBatchNumber = _bat.GlobalBatchNumber;

                DialogResult _diaresult = _bat.DialogResult;

                if (_diaresult == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    if (StrBatchNumber == "")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a batch number", "Batch Number Missing", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }

                    else
                    {

                        btnstartrobo.PerformClick();

                        btnautostart.PerformClick();


                    }
                }
    }

    catch(Exception)
    {
    }

}
```

```cs
System.Windows.Forms.Timer tmrfirst = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
private void btnautostart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    tmrfirst.Interval = 1000;
    tmrfirst.Tick += new EventHandler(tmrfirst_Tick);

    tmrfirst.Start();
}

private void tmrfirst_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnchecksignal.PerformClick();
    Thread.Sleep(100);

    if (textBox8.Text.Contains("+1"))
    {
        button14.PerformClick();
        Thread.Sleep(20);
        button42.PerformClick();

        Thread.Sleep(300);
        btnautostart.PerformClick();

    }

}
```

I tried giving thread.sleep in between, but it doesn't work. How can I fix this? Please help.

Comment: The coding style is very awkward and likely to cause hard-to-diagnose bugs.  Eliminate PerformClick() by moving code from the Click event handler to a private method.  Which can now take any arguments it needs and return a value.   Never use Thread.Sleep() to solve a problem.  And the most likely cause of the mishap, only ever subscribe the Tick event once.  Right now the Tick event handler will run multiple times for each tick.  The event subscription belongs in the constructor.  Timers you create yourself must be disposed explicitly, or they'll just keep ticking after the form is closed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your solution is not working correctly, is because both operations run in the same thread. Therefore your `Thread.Sleep(100)` is making both functions wait, not making the order change but delaying the complete  program execution.

The easiest solution to solve this would be Multithreading (see the documentation on how to implement another thread [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=netframework-4.8) and how to start it running a function [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Thread__ctor_System_Threading_ParameterizedThreadStart_))

Like this you can add the new Thread to the end of your first method or insert it into a helper method to run it only after method 1 has  completed. If you call the same function several times, maybe check if the thread already exists before creating a new one or simply close it every time your second function is finished.